# Can I run Koajs without the --harmony tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, koa

Since iojs merged into Node. I assumed I can run koajs without the `--harmony` tag (because it'll have generators from es6 supported).

So within my `server.js` file I have:

```
var koa = require('koa');
var app = koa();

app.use(function *(){
  this.body = 'Hello World';
});

app.listen(3000);
```

My `package.json` file has `"koa": "^1.1.2"`.

I run `node server.js` and get:

```
app.use(function *(){
                 ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
```

Any ideas why it's complaining? Do I still need to use the `--harmony` tag?

Thanks!

Comment: Another thing I also noticed, is there site hasn't been updated since v0.11 of  Node. Does anyone know if it hasn't been abandoned? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised I didn't come across more questions about this on the web. Anyway, i've got it to work without the `--harmony` flag.

At the moment they're working on `V2.*` which has ES6 support. You can find it on their git repo under `V2` branch https://github.com/koajs/koa.

So you need to `npm install koa@next -save` to grab the latest which currently is `"koa": "^2.0.0-alpha.3"`.

To make sure it's working you can quickly throw this in an `index.js` file then run `node index.js`:

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const app = new Koa();

// logger

app.use((ctx, next) => {
  const start = new Date;
  return next().then(() => {
    const ms = new Date - start;
    console.log(`${ctx.method} ${ctx.url} - ${ms}ms`);
  });
});

// response

app.use(ctx => {
  ctx.body = 'Hello World';
});

app.listen(3000);
```

V2 once stable will be merged into the master branch and just `npm install koa` will work. But for what I wanted, `npm install koa@next -save` worked fine :)